# Change column in data frames in list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of 78 data frames (`list_of_df`) that all have the same first column with all annotated ensembl transcript id:s, however they have the extension ".1", i e ("ENST00000448914.1" and so on) and I would like to remove that in order to match them against pure ENST-IDs.

I have tried to use lapply with a sapply inside like this:

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x)  
                 cbind(x,sapply(x$target_id, function(y) unlist(strsplit(y,split=".",fixed=T))[1])) )
```

but it takes forever, does anyone have a better idea of how to possibly do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop through the `list` of `data.frames`, and use `sub` to remove the `.` followed by numbers in the first column.

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) {
          x[,1] <-sub('\\.\\d+', '', x[,1])
           x })

#[[1]]
#   target_id value
#1 ENST000049    39
#2 ENST010393    42

#[[2]]
#   target_id value
#1 ENST123434   423
#2  ENST00838    23
```

NOTE: Even if the OP's first column is `factor`, this should work.

#### data

```
list_of_df <- list(data.frame(target_id= c("ENST000049.1", 
   "ENST010393.14"), value= c(39, 42), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
  data.frame(target_id=c("ENST123434.42", "ENST00838.22"), 
   value= c(423, 23), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code to:

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) x[,1] = unlist(strsplit(x[,1], split=".", fixed=TRUE))[1])
```

If your columns have *factor* as class, you can wrap `x[,1]` in `as.character`:

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) x[,1] = unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[,1]), split=".", fixed=TRUE))[1])
```

You could also make use of the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) x[,1] = stri_split_fixed(x[,1], ".", n=1, tokens_only=TRUE))
```